# Which is better Params or List

Tags: c#, .net

My current code is following, it is a WCF service method exposed as a proxy to the client:

```
public UnifiedDTO GetAllCardTitle(string trainSymbolOrCarLocation, 
                                  DateTime startDate, 
                                  DateTime endDate, 
                                  string procedureName = CardTitle.procedureNameTrainRuns)
```

This method takes a procedure name (as the last parameter) and rest of the parameters are the binding the input parameters, however the issue is that we do not have the flexibility in the case of parameters numbers and types changing. The project is in its initial stage, so changes will surely be made.

The options that I have is convert the method as follows:

```
public UnifiedDTO GetAllCardTitle(params object [] parameters)
```

Where we have the freedom to pass the parameters and procedure details and can accordingly bind. However, there might be a performance issue due to boxing and unboxing. It would require client application to pass the parameters with correct order and value to bind as it would be expected by underlying layers

```
public UnifiedDTO GetAllCardTitle(List<Filter> parameter, string procedureName)
```

Where `Parameter` class would be defined as:

```
public class Filter
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public string value { set; get; }
    public string dataTypeID { set; get; }

    public Filter(string _name, string _value, string _dataTypeID)
    {
        name = _name;
        value = _value;
        dataTypeID = _dataTypeID;
    }
}
```

In this method for a given procedure, we bind each parameter with its name value and `DataType`, and it would need value to typecasted to the correct data type, it has more flexibility then last method and can be passed in any order, as binding is by name. However, it would need much more due diligence from the application.

Is there still a better way to take care of this situation using something new introduced in C#.Net?

Comment: Have you considered creating a single `CardQuery` class that contains properties for all the kinds of filters you're considering? Then just have `GetAllCardTitle(CardQuery query)`

Comment: Sidenote: The overhead of boxing and unboxing is not an issue when you're talking about a WCF service, because service operation calls usually have much worse overhead -- e.g. I/O (transmitting packets over a network), network latency, etc. Boxing and unboxing is probaby lightning-fast compared to that, so you're worrying about the wrong thing.

Comment: Surprised this isn't getting upvoted more - it's a very well written question.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: For `StartDate` and `EndDate`? Yes, I'd make them `DateTime?` values.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, this would mean it would contain all possible elements and only the necessary ones are assigned, rest all can be ignored

- Do we use Nullable value types to ensure they are too Null, for a similarity with Reference types
- Also for the properties, like StartDate, which is DateTime, do we just have something like Nullable<DateTime> valueStartDate, which should map to it in the internally and can be ignored if null, this way I do not need to pass on the Parameter or for every parameter create an object Array, which contains name and value for that parameter for internal binding

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Following on from Jon Skeet's comment, the signature can be an interface (e.g. ICardQuery) that can accept different concrete classes that implement the interface like CardQuery, BigCardQuery, SmallCardQuery, etc.

Comment: I'm not really sure whether WCF service contracts allow `params` lists at all...

Comment: **It would require client application to pass the parameters with correct order and value..** Except there's nothing explicitly telling the client what that order is (other than possibly the docs). You may as well just make the signature be [`Dictionary<string, object>`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Passing+a+Dictionary+to+WCF+service). This is a terrible design.

Answer (score 1):

**None.** [Use Dynamic](http://loosexaml.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/wcf-serialization-of-dlr-dynamic-types/) object instead

To create a C# class that works with the DLR, the easiest thing to do is derive from DynamicObject. One limitation arises when trying to use a dynamic type in a WCF service. Trying to use a DynamicObject-derived type will result in a runtime exception when trying to serialize with WCF’s DataContractSerializer.

```
[DataContract]
public class SerializableDynamicObject : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
[DataMember]
private IDictionary<string,object> dynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string,object>();

#region IDynamicMetaObjectProvider implementation
public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject (Expression expression)
{
    return new SerializableDynamicMetaObject(expression, 
        BindingRestrictions.GetInstanceRestriction(expression, this), this);
}
#endregion

#region Helper methods for dynamic meta object support
internal object setValue(string name, object value) 
{
    dynamicProperties.Add(name, value);
    return value;
}

internal object getValue(string name) 
{
    object value;
    if(!dynamicProperties.TryGetValue(name, out value)) {
        value = null;
    }
    return value;
}

internal IEnumerable<string> getDynamicMemberNames() 
{
    return dynamicProperties.Keys;
}
#endregion
}


public class SerializableDynamicMetaObject : DynamicMetaObject
{
Type objType;

public SerializableDynamicMetaObject(Expression expression, BindingRestrictions restrictions, object value) 
    : base(expression, restrictions, value) 
{
    objType = value.GetType();
}

public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetMember (GetMemberBinder binder)
{
    var self = this.Expression;
    var dynObj = (SerializableDynamicObject)this.Value;
    var keyExpr = Expression.Constant(binder.Name);
    var getMethod = objType.GetMethod("getValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var target = Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(self, objType),
                                 getMethod,
                                 keyExpr);
    return new DynamicMetaObject(target,
        BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(self, objType));
}

public override DynamicMetaObject BindSetMember (SetMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject value)
{
    var self = this.Expression;
    var keyExpr = Expression.Constant(binder.Name); 
    var valueExpr = Expression.Convert(value.Expression, typeof(object));
    var setMethod = objType.GetMethod("setValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var target = Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(self, objType),
    setMethod, 
    keyExpr, 
    valueExpr);
    return new DynamicMetaObject(target,
        BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(self, objType));
}

public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames ()
{
    var dynObj = (SerializableDynamicObject)this.Value;
    return dynObj.getDynamicMemberNames();
}
}
```

One warning, dynamic members can be anything, meaning at runtime someone could assign a method to one of these fields. If this is possible in your application, you’ll need to ensure any methods assigned to the dynamic type are not serialized. I’m leaving this as an exercise for the reader.

[Taken from Here](http://loosexaml.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/wcf-serialization-of-dlr-dynamic-types/)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to allow an "Interfaced" parameter.  From that, you could handle multiple things based on the interfaced value setting.  Just shooting out a simple sample.

```
public enum eWhatAmI
{
   ListedObjects,
   StringArrays,
   Other   
}

public interface IWhatParmType
{
   eWhatAmI whatAmI { get; set; }
}

public class MyListVersion : IWhatParmType
{
   public eWhatAmI whatAmI { get; set; }
   public List<string> whatever { get; set; }

   public MyListVersion()
   {
      whatAmI = eWhatAmI.ListedObjects;
      whatever = new List<string>();
      ... build out list of strings
   }
}

public class MyArrayVersion : IWhatParmType
{
   public eWhatAmI whatAmI { get; set; }
   public string[] whatever { get; set; }

   public MyArrayVersion()
   {
      whatAmI = eWhatAmI.StringArrays;
      ... build out array of strings
   }
}
```

etc...

Then in your process for handling whatever the incoming parameter is, you can handle either way.

```
public UnifiedDTO GetAllCardTitle(IWhatParmType parameter, string procedureName)
{
   switch( parameter )
   {
      case (eWhatAmI.ListedObjects):
         // Just for grins, test to make sure object really IS expected list version object
         if( parameter is MyListVersion)
            DoViaList( (MyListVersion)parameter );
         break;

      case (eWhatAmI.StringArrays ):
         if( parameter is MyArrayVersion )
            DoViaArray( (MyArrayVersion)parameter );
         break;
   }
}

private void DoViaList( MyListVersion parm1 )
{
   .. do whatever based on the "List<string>" property
}

private void DoViaArray( MyArrayVersion parm1 )
{
   .. do whatever based on the "string []" property
}
```

Then, if you ever needed to expand a setting per a particular object instance, you could and handle within the specific sub-handler method for populating or forcing whatever defaults to be implied.